# как прописать бота что бы он выдавал один из варантов?

Tags: python

Нужно прописать бота так что бы он выдавал один из возможных вариантов но при этом с определенной вероятностью, что-то на подобии ответ "да" с 75% вероятностью а ответ "нет" с 25% или "да" - 1%, "нет" - 99%, суть в том что бы заданые события происходили с определенной вероятностью

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Генерируйте случайное число от 0 до 100 и сравнивайте с граничной вероятностью:

```
threshold_probability = 1.0          # в процентах, можно и меньше 1
rand_value = random.uniform(0, 100)  # значение float от 0 до 100

if rand_value <= threshold_probability:
   answer = 'Yes'
else:
   answer = 'No'
```